# Python Multiprocessing writing to shared file using lock

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking

I have built a very single program to understand how parallelization may help (save time).
This program simply write a list of integer in a file, and I split the treatment by range of integer.
Reading relevant question, I have put Lock, but no improvement.
The program run, but instead of having in my file, for instance, 1000000 lines, I will have 99996xx...and the number of worker do not change anything (even with one worker, the problem curiously remains...however no competition problem between worker).

May somebody explain me what is wrong ? (I have tried with opening and writing a file within the worker and then concatenate all : it runs. but I'd like to understand why I do not manage to write in a shared file with multiprocessing).

Please find below the code:

```
import csv
import time
import multiprocessing

SizeOfSet=8000000
PathCorpus='/home'
Myfile='output.csv'
MyFile=PathCorpus+'/'+Myfile

step=1000000
nb_worker=SizeOfSet//step

def worker_verrou(verrou,start,end):
    verrou.acquire()
    for k in range(start,end):
        try:
            writerfile.writerow([k])

        except:
            print('pb with writerow %i',k)

    verrou.release()    
    return


pointeurwritefile = open(MyFile, "wt")
writerfile = csv.writer(pointeurwritefile)
verrou=multiprocessing.Lock()
start_time = time.time()  
jobs=[]
for k in range(nb_worker):
    print('Starting process number %i', k)       
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_verrou, args=(verrou, k*step,(k+1)*step))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
for j in jobs:
    j.join()        
    print '%s.exitcode = %s' % (j.name, j.exitcode)

interval = time.time() - start_time  
print('Total time in seconds:', interval)


print('ended')
```

Comment: Firstly you are serialising parallel tasks. The line `verrou.acquire()` means that each `Process` that gets the lock, locks out all others until it has finished.

Comment: Ok. But without Lock (verrou), the problem remains, my output file is not complete. Even with one process (i.e step =SizeOfSet)

Comment: Perhaps you need to close the files once all the writes have completed.

Comment: Thx. No, I have tried with `pointeurwritefile.close()` at the end of this program. No change.

Comment: It looks like the last job (or process) do not until the end. the messing value are always at the end...However the exit-code is zero...